# Why do we make the non-havdalah Brachos at havdalah if they're not necessary for the mitzvah?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, havdalah

As discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84552/9682), not having spices or a flame does not prevent one from doing havdalah.

All of them have their reasons for being a part of the service (see [this Aish article](http://www.aish.com/sh/ht/as/48970721.html), point #5, for those reasons), but they all seemingly have nothing to do with havdalah so much as the exiting of Shabbos in general. In light of that, why don't we just make the havdalah brachah and say the other Brachos at some other point during the night? Is it just for convenience, that since we're sitting down to do this mitzvah, we might as well do the others also, or is there some deeper reason that they should be done together?

Comment: I apologize for the fire-related puns scattered throughout the question. I hope I don't ignite anyone's ire with them, or get fired by some hothead.

Comment: You can ask the same question about shehechiyanu at kiddush on Yom Tov which can also be said at any time during the day (like we do on Yom Kippur)

Comment: IMSMC the dispute between Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai (Brachos 52?) regarding the order  of the service (and associated acronyms) strongly suggest that it is not just a matter of convenience.

Comment: @Loewian You mean the Yaknehaz discussion? Not sure where that's located, but that's a fair point.

Comment: @loewi I don't see any such suggestion. We debate applications of Tadir for putting on Tefillin or Tzitzit first and doing them at the same time is definitely just a matter of conveniece

Comment: *mitzva haba l'yadcha*

Comment: @Loewian Then we should do it with Atah Chonantanu. Has it really come to your hand only at havdalah?

Comment: You want people to be playing with fire and spices during shemoneh esrei?

Comment: @Loewian Some play with shofaros in Shemoneh Esrei. Would you rather they do it before Maariv, or just drop everything at Tzeis and do it then?

Answer (score 1):

The Aish link you brought is very good in setting the tone for what you know and want to find out, so thank  you.

In regards to borei moreih ha'esh, the Gemara brings the idea of waiting to say the bracha contrary to saying it right away just as a minhag, not too much reasoning there (see Pesachim 54a, R' Yehuda holds and R' Yochanan says halacha is like him-R' Yochanan usually the authoritative Tanna as far as psak from Gemara goes and we see that follow through for Rambam Hil Shabbas 29:24 and Tur Shulchan Aruch 296:1)

In Shulchan Aruch, the Rema notes the minhag of pouring the wine first as a sign of a bracha (for the week) and specifically over the meorei haesh-- no reasoning.) The first reasoning that I found was is in the same siman of the Shulchan Aruch HaRav (Seif 5) quoting the Levush (271:10) that pouring the wine to put out the candle signifies the candle's use specifically for the mitzvah of havdalah and brings in the name of the Rema (mentioned earlier) that we rub our eyes with the wine to signify our enjoyment of and love for the mitzvah.

Seemingly this wouldn't be an opportunity without the candle for the wine but my Rosh yeshiva said this wasn't the reason, just the way the minhag is fulfilled through the meorei ha'esh and bsamim being a part of Havdalah. He further mentioned that it's logical (and potentially why it's hard to find mefarshim say so explicitly) that in general, saying something over wine in Yiddishkite signifies an importance ceremonial emphasis of kedusha as we see it used for kiddush/Havdalah for Shabbas and festivals, kidushin of the chupah, Birkas hamazon with a zimun. It in a sense anchors down the mitzvah in a mehudar way so how much more so when you anchor the two other related brachos related to Motzei Shabbas.

Fun practical minhag some have as an outcome of saying all three brachos together is the ability to light the candles required for melaveh malka (as in Kittzur Shulchan Aruch 96:12) with the Havdalah torch before putting it out with wine. Hopes this helps.

Comment: So, TLDR, no actual reason besides minhag yisrael?

Comment: Ok, will consider length in future (wanted to show you the main sources so you see that they don't explicitly talk about it.) Now, that doesn't mean the minhag is the only reason or has no reason, it is a minhag whose reason is logical and obvious in the sense that wine in Yiddishkite represents something chosuv (like listed examples) so might as well connect the two other Motzei Shabbas brachos to that glass of wine.

Comment: Still not clear - how did the minhag develop?

Comment: As already answered in first answer, source is from Gemara Pesachim 54a in the name of R' Yehuda and followed by R' Yochanan (makes it authoritative.)

Comment: @DonielF The idea he writes about preferring to do certain blessings on a Kos is related to what I said in my answer (that prompted this q) about it being an honor.

Comment: @ChassidisheBochur I didn't ask for a source. I asked for a reason.

Comment: @DonielF I understand, part of the explanation was that there weren't any reasons given by any mefarshim (surprisingly) and just the source was given. I shared my Rosh Yeshiva's explanation for why that is (because it's--his words not mine--logical/obvious) in line with what Double AA wrote. Realize it was long, new to the community but it seems like a lot of your questions were addressed in the original answer, I'd appreciate your understanding based on the Be Nice rules to new people.

Comment: @ChassidisheBochur Not intending to not be nice, regardless of whether you're new or not. I was just seeking clarification, which you've sufficiently provided. Thank you.